# Change column names in python pandas using list comprehension

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list-comprehension

I am currently trying to change the following column names:

```
Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2         <----- Column names
    Alfa       Beta             <----- Data
```

Into:

```
 2016 | 2017
 Alfa   Beta
```

I have used:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r"Unnamed\:\s\d+"," ",x))
```

To replace the column names with a blank space, but I want to create a loop so automatically can be replaced into 2016 and 2017

[Additionally]
I made this to create the list of values

```py
for i in range(len(df.columns[:])):
    i+=2016
    str(i)
```

Result gives:

```
2016
2017
```

Is there any method in which I can substitute those values into the list comprehension?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454054/42346

Comment: i assume u get these headers when u read in the data. you could set the column names directly when doing so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think list comprehension here is not necessary, only assign `range` with start from variable:

```
start = 2016
df.columns = range(start, start + len(df.columns))
print (df)
   2016  2017
0  Alfa  Beta
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: int(x.strip('Unnamed: '))+2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumped into this, to do what OP asked with list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [re.sub(r'Unnamed: [12]', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0).strip('Unnamed: '))+2015), item) for item in df.columns]
```

I know this is a a really long one-liner but OP asked for it, but agree with others, do it manually is the way to go unless the df is huge with a lot of columns. The lambda function portion should be a stand alone function which will allow much more flexibility for more advanced manipulation.

this one line can change below header:

```
    col1    Unnamed: 1  col3    Unnamed: 2
0    1        Alfa        3       Beta
```

to:

```
  col1  2016    col3    2017
0   1   Alfa     3      Beta
```