# Create dataframe, get columns from the list

Tags: python, pandas

I ran the PostgreSQL query to get all columns names from a table "city"

`SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = city`

It returns the list, looks like this:

`[('city_id',), ('city',), ('country_id',), ('last_update',)]`

Next step is to create a dataframe, with the columns from this list, (the rows is gonna be a result from another query)

Like this:
`df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=[_list_]`

The tricky part is that I can't just write all the columns as usual - it has to be a mutable value if I want it to work with another query with different columns

Comment: `columns` argument in `pandas.DataFrame()` means column names, what is `_list_`?

Comment: it is the list i recive by doing a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually easier just to create a dataframe "by default" and then rename all the columns

(i skipped the connection and creation of the cursor part)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = city")
results2 = cursor.fetchall()
print(results2)
df = pandas.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
df.columns = df.columns[:0].tolist() + results2
print(df)
```

Results:

```
[('city_id',), ('city',), ('country_id',), ('last_update',)]

     0                     1   2                          3
0    1       ACorua(LaCorua)  87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
1  146  Donostia-SanSebastin  87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
2  181                  Gijn  87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
3  388       Ourense(Orense)  87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
4  459  SantiagodeCompostela  87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783

      city_id                  city     country_id                last_update
0           1       ACorua(LaCorua)             87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
1         146  Donostia-SanSebastin             87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
2         181                  Gijn             87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
3         388       Ourense(Orense)             87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
4         459  SantiagodeCompostela             87 2021-03-22 12:50:22.061783
```

[how to rename columns in pandas using a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454042/how-to-rename-columns-in-pandas-using-a-list)